# Problem with mods on Morrowind

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I've been playing Elder Scrolls Oblivion for almost three years and I love it. I got Morrowind Game of the Year Edition last year and I started to play it. I like mods, so I downloaded lots of them to make the game a little bit funny. But when I start the game, some mods don't work. I have no idea why this happens, I even checked on the Construction Set and I can see the new NPC's and objects, but they never show up in the game.

For example, I downloaded a couple of house mods and they work fine(Cave House, Warrior's Rest). I have a mod for massive teleportation, and also works. But I downloaded new quest mods(Regin of fire, The great tribe of the North, Romance, The ring of the vampire, A drow history) but they don't work. Can anyone help me, please? I really love to play this quest mods, I have lots of them for Oblivion.

Comment: Since mods aren't native to the game, it will be difficult to get an answer here for you.  You can try and contact the mod creators for help but other than that, you'll likely not find an answer on here.

Comment: What do you mean by "they don't work"? for example, in "The great tribe..." are the new areas added by it in the game, or do you just can't start the quest?

Comment: Expecting us to get your specific set of mods working isnt really something we can help with; everyone is going to run different mods, and they aren't all compatible with others. Your best bet is to talk to the mod creators. Beyond that, we can't provide any help.

Comment: @Deltharis That mod, for example, adds new areas on Solstheim, also creatures and NPC's. But when I run the game, those new elements never show up. I had once another quest mod with new areas and characters, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morrowind modding was almost an accidental feature and wasn't really supported very well by the game engine. One of the problems caused by this is that many things that *can* be changed in the Construction Set are ignored when loaded into an existing save, because the original version is already part of the save.

The end result is that many mods don't function correctly unless you **start a new character**. This is enough of a known issue in Morrowind modding that it's standard practice to only install mods at the beginning, and then to never add new mods after beginning a new playthrough. Adding mods after may or may not work, and the risk of weird bugs can be quite high depending on what kind of things the mod changes.

Comment: Ok, I will start a new character with all of the mods enabled and I'll let you know

Comment: I started a new character with some mods, but they didn't work again. I even dowloaded MWSE, although the GOTY edition has the MGE and this contains an internal version of MWSE.

Comment: @Ethan It sounds like there may be a different problem now. It might be useful to ask a fresh question, with a lot of detail of how MW was installed and how/which mods were installed, so the community can solve it.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301286/morrowind-doesn-t-launch-under-windows-7-sometimes-with-the-error-the-applicat