# Morrowind doesn’t launch under Windows 7 (sometimes with the error "the application crashed")

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I recently reinstalled my OS with Windows 7 32 bit and I installed *Morrowind GOTY*, but when I try to run the MGE-GUI it doesn't launch at all. I've read that it needs administrator privileges, so I changed the permissions but it still doesn't launch. I also changed the privileges of the others .exe files (as suggested in the web) and nothing happened. Sometimes I get an error message displaying "the application crashed".

I have already installed NetFramework 4.0, DirectX 10 and everything it needs to run. I don't know what's happening now, cause I've played Morrowind before and I never experienced this issue. I can even run other games on my PC without problems, like *Elder Scrolls Oblivion*, *Dragon Age Origins*, and so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution! I read in a blog (can't remember the url now, sorry) where an usser had this same issue. She reinstalled the Directx and the MGE GUI run. I reinstalled then Directx9 instead of the 10, and now the MGE GUI runs fine as before reinstalling my laptop. So, issue solved.